# Cannot import module in ipython

Tags: python, module, ipython

Hi I am having difficult importing nilearn in ipython

I can see that the module is available in my conda environment but when I go into ipython and try and import it I get the import error: no module named nilearn and I can see that it is not an available module.

Could anybody please explain where I am going wrong?

Many Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `nilearn` first; it's not part of the standard Anaconda distro.

Open the Anaconda command prompt and enter

```
pip install nilearn
```

Comment: Thank you but nilearn is already installed (conda install nilearn) and is available in the conda environment - it is just when I am in ipython that it is not available

Comment: Do you have more than one environment set up?

Comment: Yes- the one I am working in is called MRS_conda. When I am in this environment - and I list the available modules nilearn is there. But when I start ipython (still in this environment) it is not there?

Comment: I don't have a way to test this right now, but I seem to remember that ipython does not automatically start in the current conda environment. If you just start python, can you import the module from there?

Comment: Dear Tim - thankyou that appears to be the problem. It imports fine in Python. Do you know how to force ipython to start in the current environment?